# Is List truly invariant in Python

Tags: python, mypy

I have a script `toy.py`, and I find its behavior kind of confusing.

```
from typing import List


class A:
    a = 1

class B(A):
    b = 2


def func(input_arg: List[A]) -> None:
    """Debugging mypy."""
    print(f"{input_arg=:}")
    print(f"{type(input_arg)=:}")
```

If I append

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = B()
    reveal_type([arg1])
    func([arg1])
```

mypy passes:

```
mypy toy.py
toy.py:22:17: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[toy.B*]"
```

but if I instead append

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg2 = [B()]
    reveal_type(arg2)
    func(arg2)
```

which I thought is equivalent to the first case, I see error

```
mypy toy.py
toy.py:26:17: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[toy.B*]"
toy.py:27:10: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "List[B]"; expected "List[A]"
toy.py:27:10: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
toy.py:27:10: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

If List is invariant, why would the first case pass?

```
mypy --version
mypy 0.931
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior has to do with the way mypy uses context to infer types. When calling a function, the type hints for *parameters* in the function's definition can be used to infer the type of passed *arguments*.

However, mypy only allows this 'context-based inference' *within a single statement*. The following examples from the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_inference_and_annotations.html#context-in-type-inference) illustrates a more extreme case:

This is allowed, and uses single-statement context to infer the type of an empty list as `list[int]`:

> ```py
> def foo(arg: list[int]) -> None:
>    print('Items:', ''.join(str(a) for a in arg))
>
> foo([])  # OK
> ```

but here, the context would need to filter up from the statement `foo(a)` up to the assignment `a = []`, similar to your second example, but mypy isn't able to do that.

> ```py
> def foo(arg: list[int]) -> None:
>    print('Items:', ''.join(str(a) for a in arg))
>
> a = []  # Error: Need type annotation for "a"
> foo(a)
> ```

---

Interestingly, using an assignment expression also doesn't work: the assignment statement is completed before the function is called, so no context can be passed:

```py
def foo(arg: list[int]) -> None:
   print('Items:', ''.join(str(a) for a in arg))

foo(a := [1.1])  # Error: "a" has incompatible type "list[float]"
```