# Python: Type resolution for list subscription types with base and derived classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, pylance

I'm developing a Python library to aid in data management in chemistry research groups. The core of the library defines a `Dataset` class composed of classes such as `CharacterizationMethod`, `RawData`, etc. These latter classes are to be used as base classes for users to inherit from, where the user-created classes will be specific to their research. The inherited attributes and methods will ensure that the user classes work with the tools provided by my library.

I'm running into an issue with the typing of function arguments for user-created classes. Here's some example code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class BaseComponent:
    name: str = ""

@dataclass
class BaseParent:
    components: list[BaseComponent] = field(default_factory=list)

@dataclass
class UserComponent(BaseComponent):
    pass

@dataclass
class UserParent(BaseParent):
    pass

user_component = UserComponent()
user_components = [user_component, user_component]

user_parent1 = UserParent(components=[user_component])  # ok
user_parent2 = UserParent(components=user_components)  # not ok
user_parent3 = UserParent(components=[*user_components])  # ok

def create_user_parent1(component: UserComponent) -> UserParent:
    return UserParent(components=[component])  # ok

def create_user_parent2(components: list[UserComponent]) -> UserParent:
    return UserParent(components=components)  # not ok

def create_user_parent3(components: list[UserComponent]) -> UserParent:
    return UserParent(components=[*components])  # ok
```

The comments show where my type checker (`pylance` in VS Code) is complaining. The [same issue was discussed here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/955), and it seems that it has to do with the fact that `list` type arguments are invariant. Changing the attribute in the base classes to `Sequence[T]` fixes the typing issue I'm asking about but raises several others in methods which assume that the attribute is a `list[T]`.

It's also worth noting that this only seems to be an issue in `pylance`. When I run `mypy` on the above code it has no complaints.

For educational purposes, I'm still interested in trying to understand

- why the seemingly equivalent arguments in the above example are treated differently by `pylance`
- why `pylance` and `mypy` don't provide the same analysis
- why, in `pylance`, mutable generic types (e.g. `list`) have invariant argument types but immutable generic types (e.g. `Sequence`) have covariant argument types.

For practical purposes I'm just trying to figure out if this is a code smell indicating a problem with the architecture. The other approach I could take is to define interfaces using `Protocol` classes with the `@runtime_checkable` decorator to ensure that user-created classes adhere to the protocols defined in my library. When I went down the `Protocol` route initially I ran into a situation where each class (e.g. `CharacterizationMethod`) had both a `Protocol` to define the interface and a mixin class to give the users some of the boilerplate methods used by my library, and it seemed redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a covariant mutable version of List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814180/is-there-a-covariant-mutable-version-of-list)

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71404423/is-list-truly-invariant-in-python) discusses the difference between `some_list` and `[*some_list]` from typing perspective.

Comment: And `mypy` correctly rejects this code too, not only pylance (you can check [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=898d4d9b29ffdb2c8eb13f4aa338e2bc))